# cross domain issue with window.opener.location.href

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cross-domain

I have a asp.net website where i can book rail tickets. 
Suppose my website URL is test.mybooking.com. I also have a reserved URL for this wbsite, say res-test.mybooking.com

For booking a rail ticket i am redirecting to a url "rail.mybooking.com" in a popup window. which is a sub domain provided by my vendor. 
After selecting a source and destination and other details vendor is redirected to a page "test.mybooking.com/RailDetail.aspx", in the same popup window.

On this page I have a code which finds the opener location of parent window using following code :

```
var str = window.opener.location.href;
```

which finds parent window, closes the popup window and redirects a parent window to the bookingcart page for payment.

Code works great with test.mybooking.com and gives error with res-test.mybooking.com.

Comment: It sounds like some critical information might be missing from this question.. from what I understand your script stops working when you use replace test.mybooking.com with res-test.mybooking.com. However, there must be something else that sets apart the URLs than the sequence of characters in them.

Comment: Or is your issue that in one case (test.mybooking.com) your window.opener is rail.mybooking.com, and in the other case (res-test.mybooking.com) it's some-other-domain.com? In that case I'm pretty sure it won't work for security seasons, the browser requires you to use the same domain.